Add Popup message After Upload in Nextjs File Sharing APP
I'm building a file sharing app I have build till the upload section when file is uploaded to firebase the progress bar is show to 100% so I need to add a pop up msg after upload. also how to remove it onclicking the cross btn.
upload form:
function UploadForm({uploadBtnClick, progress}) {
    const [file,setFile]=useState();
    const [errorMsg,setErrorMsg]= useState();
    const onFileSelect=(file)=>{
        console.log(file)
        if(file&&file.size>100000000){
            console.log("Size is Greater than 100MB")
            setErrorMsg('Maximum File Upload Size Is 100MB')
            return;
        }
        setErrorMsg(null)
        setFile(file)
    }
  return (
    <div className='text-center'>
<div class="flex items-center justify-center w-full">
    <label for="dropzone-file" class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center w-full h-64 border-2 border-blue-300 border-dashed rounded-lg cursor-pointer bg-blue-50 dark:hover:bg-bray-800 dark:bg-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:border-gray-600 dark:hover:border-gray-500 dark:hover:bg-gray-600">
        <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center pt-5 pb-6">
            <svg class="w-12 h-12 mb-4 text-blue-500 dark:text-blue-400" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 20 16">
                <path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M13 13h3a3 3 0 0 0 0-6h-.025A5.56 5.56 0 0 0 16 6.5 5.5 5.5 0 0 0 5.207 5.021C5.137 5.017 5.071 5 5 5a4 4 0 0 0 0 8h2.167M10 15V6m0 0L8 8m2-2 2 2"/>
            </svg>
            <p class="mb-2 text-lg md:text-2xl text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400"><strong class="font-semibold text-primary">Click to upload</strong> or <strong className='text-primary'>drag</strong> and <strong className='text-primary'>drop</strong></p>
            <p class="text-xs text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">SVG, PNG, JPG or GIF (MAX Size: 100MB)</p>
        </div>
        <input id="dropzone-file" type="file" class="hidden" onChange={(event)=>onFileSelect(event.target.files[0])} />
    </label>

</div> 
{errorMsg?<AlertMsg msg={errorMsg}/>:null}
{file?<FilePreview file={file} removeFile={()=>setFile(null)}/>:null}

{progress>0?<ProgressBar progress={progress}/>:<button disabled={!file} className='p-2 bg-primary text-white w-[30%] rounded-full mt-5 disabled:bg-gray-400' onClick={()=>uploadBtnClick(file)}>
    Upload
</button>}
{/* {progress=100?<ProgressBar progress={progress}/>:<AlertNotify/>} */}
{/* {progress=100?<AlertNotify/>:null} */}
    </div>
    
  )
}

export default UploadForm

Alert notify:
import React from 'react'

function AlertNotify() {
  return (
    <div>
        <div role="alert" className="rounded-xl border border-gray-100 bg-white p-4">
  <div className="flex items-start gap-4">
    <span className="text-green-600">
      <svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        fill="none"
        viewBox="0 0 24 24"
        strokeWidth="1.5"
        stroke="currentColor"
        className="h-6 w-6"
      >
        <path
          strokeLinecap="round"
          strokeLinejoin="round"
          d="M9 12.75L11.25 15 15 9.75M21 12a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z"
        />
      </svg>
    </span>

    <div className="flex-1">
      <strong className="block font-medium text-gray-900"> Uploaded Successfully </strong>

      <p className="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-700">Your File Has Been Uploaded Successfully</p>
    </div>

    <button className="text-gray-500 transition hover:text-gray-600">
      <span className="sr-only">Dismiss popup</span>

      <svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        fill="none"
        viewBox="0 0 24 24"
        strokeWidth="1.5"
        stroke="currentColor"
        className="h-6 w-6"
      >
        <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" />
      </svg>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default AlertNotify

this is the code i used but the pop up does not comes after the process it remain as ui through out
{progress=100?<AlertNotify/>:null}

upload btn is the pop up msg

